# Sub string in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I sub a string according the 3th character
for example: I have the string "aaa://Google/gmail"
and I want to get a new string 
till the 3th "/", new string = "aaa://Google/"

Comment: I'm sure this can be Googled rather easily. I would start by typing in `Sub string in javascript`

Comment: You might want to try some regular expressions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask :  'Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? '

Comment: You are looking for a combination of `substring()` and `indexOf()` in javascript.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do

```
var str = "aaa://Google/gmail",
    matches = str.split('/');
str = matches.slice(0, 3).join('/') + ( matches.length > 3 ? '/' : '' )
```

If you don't care about the trailing slash, it's simpler:

```
 "aaa://Google/gmail".split('/').slice(0,3).join('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try a regex:

```
var s = "aaa://Google/gmail";
var regex = /.*?\/.*?\/.*?\// // or more sophisticated: /(?:.*?\/){3}/
s.match(regex);
```

additionally this looks like you try to get `document.location.host` (and maybe `document.location.protocol`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use match:

```
var s = 'http://www.google.com/whatever';
var match = s.match(/^[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\//);

alert(match && match[0]);  // http://www.google.com/
```